# efficient algorithm to find the minimum cost path

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum

There is a given set of cities lets say.. A,B,C,D,E,F,G. The problem is to find the minimum cost path that covers the cities A,B,C,F. It is essential that the path covers the cities A,B,C,F. The path can, (but does not have to) go through any of the other given cities (D,E,G). Repeating a path is allowed. The path should start and end at A.
How should i go about tackling a problem along similar lines?

Comment: i have an adjacency list representation of a graph for the problem, now i am trying to implement dijkstra's algorithm to find the minimum cost paths for the 'interesting cities' as suggested by @Kolmar.

Answer (score 3):

That's a variant of [Travelling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) (TSP) in disguise.

You can see that, if you mark every city as "needed to be covered" (I'll call those "interesting" henceforth). The variant of TSP, where you are allowed to visit a node more than once, is still NP-complete.

So, knowing that the complexity of every exact solution to your problem would be exponential in the number of interesting cities, you can procede as follows:

First, precompute the shortest paths between interesting cities. This can be done with [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) run from every interesting city or [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm). Then either try every permutation of the order of visiting interesting cities; or use some existing TSP solver or heuristic algorithm.

So the simplest implementation goes like this:

1. Apply Floyd-Warshall to the city graph. It's much simpler to implement than Dijkstra's. I've found a nice [PDF](http://web.mit.edu/tabbott/Public/tj-sct-lectures/spath.pdf) with their comparison. It gets you the matrix with all the shortest paths for AB, AC, AF, BC, BF and CF. If you need to get the actual path as in sequence of cities, look at [Path reconstruction section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Path_reconstruction) in Wikipedia.
2. Try every permutation of the order of visiting interesting cities except A (i.e., only B, C and F). If you use C++, Python or Ruby, they have permutation function in the standard library. For other languages you may want to use a third-party library or search Stack Overflow for an algorithm.
3. Find the permutation with the lowest total cost of a path. E.g., for permutation C-F-B, the total cost is AC+CF+FB+BA. You already have all those values from Floyd-Warshall, so you can simply sum them.

If you have V total cities and N interesting cities, the runtime of this implementation will be about O(V<sup>3</sup> + N!·N)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you elaborate on the final bullet point?

Comment: @user269952 I'm sorry, I thought it would be a more complex solution than the second one, but with an exponential time instead of factorial. But now I thought a bit more, and it seems to give exponential memory as well. So I've removed it. If you need to quickly implement some solution for small cases then pemutation method is simpler, because many modern languages (e.g., C++, Python, Ruby) have a function to generate permutations in standard library. And for max efficiency it's better to use heuristics (e.g. simulated annealing) or third-party solvers.

Comment: by "precompute the shortest paths between interesting cities" do you mean i find shortest paths for all possible combinations of the cities A,B,C,F in the above example? that would be the shortest paths from A-B , A-C, A-F, B-C, B-F, C,F

Comment: @user269952 Yes, Floyd-Warshall algorithm does just this: finds the shortest path between any 2 nodes, and Dijkstra's finds shortest paths from 1 node to all the others, so you would have to run it from every interesting city.

Comment: So i apply dijkstra's from all interesting cities to other interesting cities and store the values; Then i go through these values and find the route from A to any of the other interesting cities (lets say B) with the least distance. I browse through the values again and find the next shortest distance from B to any of the other interesting cities. I repeat this until all of the interesting cities are covered. Finally to find the shortest distance back to A, i apply Floyd-Warshall algorithm. Is this correct or am i completely out of track here?

Comment: @user269952 See my edit with a possble implementation

Comment: i just did some research on the floyd warshall algorithm and apparently it cannot be applied to a adjacency list graph which is what i am working with. so i guess i'll have to go with dijkstra's.